# ValidationException in modified todolist example [Play! Framework 2]

Tags: playframework

The todolist example from the 300-page PDf documentation in 2.0 RC1 worked fine for me. Then I decided to add this email validation to the Task model:

```
@Required @Email
public String label;
```

The newTask action is still:

```
public static Result newTask() {
    Form<Task> filledForm = taskForm.bindFromRequest();

    if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(
            views.html.index.render(Task.all(), filledForm) 
        );
    } else {
        Task.create(filledForm.get());
        return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
    }
}
```

When a todo is formatted as an email, the item is saved as expected.

But, I expected that the check by filledForm.hasErrors() would catch todos not formatted as email address, but instead, the application throws:

```
! @69d929n08 - Internal server error, for request [POST /tasks] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[ValidationException: validation failed for: models.Task]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:65) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0-RC1]
...
```

How can I validate using the @Email annotation and not get an exception?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue, make sure you are using `play.data.validation.Constraints.Email` instead of `com.avaje.ebean.validation.Email`.  That was my issue.